# Gulp error occurred on running gulp default command

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

When I'm trying to run the `gulp default` command on **git bash** an error occurred!

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
> at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\wamp64\www\WP-PROJECTS\thfireplaces.ca\demo_new\wp-content\themes\thfireplaces\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
> at Gulp.task (C:\wamp64\www\WP-PROJECTS\thfireplaces.ca\demo_new\wp-content\themes\thfireplaces\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
> at Object. (C:\wamp64\www\WP-PROJECTS\thfireplaces.ca\demo_new\wp-content\themes\thfireplaces\gulpfile.js:181:6)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at requireOrImport (C:\Users\Momin Riyadh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11) {
> generatedMessage: false,
> code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
> actual: false,
> expected: true,
> operator: '=='
> }

Here is my machine details node version `12.14.1` npm version `7.0.2` gulp local version `4.0.2`!

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "instaHtmlQuickPack",
  "version": "0.6.5",
  "description": "Html Quick Pack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "gulp default"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=2.1.8"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "#"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "wordpress",
    "theme",
    "bootstrap"
  ],
  "author": "Azizul Hoq",
  "license": "GPL-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "#"
  },
  "homepage": "#",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.12",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.7.0",
    "gulp-clone": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-ignore": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-merge": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sequence": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "merge2": "^1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.11.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-csscomb": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-filenames": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```js
// Defining base pathes
var basePaths = {
    node: './node_modules/',
    src: './src/',
    assets: './assets/',
    vendorsCss: './src/vendors/css/',
    vendorsJs: './src/vendors/js/'
};

var jsFileList = [
        basePaths.vendorsJs+'*.js',
        basePaths.src+'js/custom-script.js'
    ];

var cssFileList = [
        basePaths.vendorsCss+'*.css'
    ];
    

   // console.log(jsFileList);

// Defining requirements
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-cssnano');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var merge2 = require('merge2');
var ignore = require('gulp-ignore');
var del = require('del');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var csscomb = require('gulp-csscomb');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


// browser-sync watched files
// automatically reloads the page when files changed
var browserSyncWatchFiles = [
    basePaths.assets+'css/*.css',
    basePaths.assets+'js/*.js',
    basePaths.src+'media/**',
    './*.html',
    './*.php'
];

var browserSyncOptions = {
    proxy: "http://localhost/WP-PROJECTS/thfireplaces.ca/demo_new/",
    notify: false
};

// Run:
// gulp browser-sync
// Starts browser-sync task for starting the server.
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(browserSyncWatchFiles, browserSyncOptions);
});

// Run:
// gulp sass
// Compiles SCSS files in CSS
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(basePaths.src+'sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        // .pipe(csscomb())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.assets+'css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


// Run:
// gulp concat-css
// concat css file from src
gulp.task('concat-css', function() {
    return gulp.src(cssFileList)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.assets+'css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Run:
// gulp concat-js
// concat js file from src
gulp.task('concat-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsFileList)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.assets+'js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


// Run:
// gulp minifycss
// Minifies CSS files
gulp.task('minifycss',  function(){
  return gulp.src([basePaths.assets+'css/bundle.css', basePaths.assets+'css/theme.css'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(concat('theme.min.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:false,safe: true}))
    .pipe(minifyCSS({
            reduceIdents: {
                keyframes: false
            },
            discardUnused: {
                keyframes: false
            },
            discardComments: {
                removeAll: true
            }
        }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.assets+'css/'));
});

// Run:
// gulp minifyjs
// Minifies js files
gulp.task('minifyjs', function() {
    return gulp.src(basePaths.assets+'js/bundle.js')
        .pipe(plumber())
        // .pipe(concat('bundle.min.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.assets+'js/'));
});


// Run:
// gulp clean
// Remove file
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del([
    'css/*',
    // here we use a globbing pattern to match everything inside the `mobile` folder
    'js/*.js',
    // we don't want to clean this file though so we negate the pattern
    '!css/*.min.css',
    '!js/*.min.js'
  ]);
});




// Run:
// gulp imagemin
// Running image optimizing task
gulp.task('imagemin', function(){
    gulp.src(basePaths.src+'img/**')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.assets+'img/'))
});


// Run:
// gulp watch
// Starts watcher. Watcher runs gulp sass task on changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    // gulp.watch(basePaths.src+'sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(basePaths.src+'sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch(cssFileList,gulp.series('concat-css'));
    gulp.watch(jsFileList,gulp.series('concat-js'));
    gulp.watch(basePaths.src+'img/**', gulp.series('imagemin'));
    //gulp.watch('browser-sync');
});



//task register
// gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'sass', 'concat-css', 'concat-js', 'browser-sync']);
// gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'concat-css', 'concat-js', 'minifycss', 'minifyjs', 'imagemin']);

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch', 'sass', 'concat-css', 'concat-js', 'browser-sync'));
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('sass', 'concat-css', 'concat-js', 'minifycss', 'minifyjs', 'imagemin'));
```